# JIRA JQL Query - Filter by multiple texts on summary field

Tags: jira, jql

I have been trying to write the query in JIRA using JQL to exclude user stories having the following text in the summary. How to optimise or union the multiple AND conditions.

> ```
> project = "FOA" AND type = story AND labels = API and summary !~ TECH_STORY
> AND summary !~ TEST_STORY AND summary !~ ABC_Test AND summary !~ 'Drop B'
> AND SUMMARY !~ DOCUMENTATION AND summary !~ XYZ_Test and summary !~ Debt
> ```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be working but I would urge you to test it in your environment:

```
summary !~ "first_match OR second_match OR third_match"
```

Source: [JIRA Advanced Searching](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/advanced-searching-operators-reference-764478341.html#Advancedsearching-operatorsreference-DOES_NOT_CONTAINDOESNOTCONTAIN:!~) and [JIRA text search syntax](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/search-syntax-for-text-fields-764478343.html#Searchsyntaxfortextfields-OR)